# How to Change the size of print just half in open ERP?

Tags: python, odoo, rml

Hello I am new in Open ERP. I have a task to do the print size just half. for this I am doing changes in account_print_invoice.rml as

```
 **<template pageSize="(595.0, 842.0)" title="Invoices" author="OpenERP S.A.(sales@openerp.com)" allowSplitting="20">**
```

I am doing the height of the template just half as 421.The page is viewed as half but the other content of the page is not appearing.

Plz help me how I can do the same dynamically or do the change in rml file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change height and width of frame also.
Frame looks like

```
<frame id="first" x1="1.3cm" y1="6.5cm" height="19.0cm" width="19.0cm"/>
```

or

```
<frame id="first" x1="62.0" y1="57.0" width="723" height="481"/>
```